# Finding points along lines, given lengths along those lines, using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing

I have one layer with a network of lines and a second layer with its associated line and its distance along that line.

Is there a way to generate points for all these rows along their associated lines?

Answer (score 1):

> Tested on QGIS 3.6

You could create a Virtual Layer.

Assume your network of lines layer is called `"Lines"` and has a column named `"Id"`.  And the second layer is called `"distances"` with a column `"LineId"` for the associated line Id and a column `"Chainage"` for the distances along the lines.

Create a Virtual Layer with the query:

```sql
SELECT d.LineId,
       d.Chainage,
       Line_Interpolate_Point(l.geometry,d.Chainage) AS geom
FROM distances AS d
JOIN Lines AS l ON d.LineId=l.Id
```

This will give a new layer of points located along the lines with the attributes `"LineId"` and `"Chainage"`.